# Wrong routing golang using julienschmidt/httprouter

Tags: go

I'm new in golang, and I useing framework julienschmidt/httprouter for routing my endpoint.
I have code router like this:

```
router.GET("/area", m.Chaining(Areas, standardChain...))
router.GET("/area/:districtId", m.Chaining(Area, standardChain...))
```

I call request with curl like this:

```
curl --location --request GET 'localhost:9000/area/?start=20210602'
```

the router execute Areas not Area ? why not execute Area, and how to be execute Area with empty path parameter ?

Comment: The url matches /area, not /area/:district

Comment: yeah, why not match on /area/:district, i have request with path param but empty. ?

Comment: In `/area/?start=... `, `start` is a query param. In `/param/:districtId`, `:districtId` is a path param. `/param/someId` would match the second route.

Comment: how about this one GET 'localhost:9000/area/  ,this query param is empty but in my code always redirect to Areas ?

Comment: the main idea is i want to validate empty districtId. but i can not do that, because the router goes to Areas to Area.

Comment: You should read about how path matching is done. The behavior you observe is consistent with all the routers I know.

Comment: you correct @BurakSerdar, the only one I need is changes the endpoint. so i can validate the path param.

Answer (score 0):

the solution is change the endpoint.

```
router.GET("/area", m.Chaining(Areas, standardChain...))
router.GET("/areaId/:districtId", m.Chaining(Area, standardChain...))
router.GET("/areaId", m.Chaining(Area, standardChain...))
```

and can validate districtId when the endpoint go to areaId.